# How to make Javascript functions "defined" while using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here were many problems that occured and I found a way to make them 'validated' but, is this safe? if not can you help me make it right?

```
$('document').ready(function{
    var $demo = $('demo');
    $demo.onclick(function runAlpha(){
        //do something with alpha
    });
    $demo.onclick(function runBeta() {
        //do something with beta
    });
});

function runAlpha(){}
function runBeta(){}
```

the functions outside of the jquery are left blank to be a null and javascript recognizes that its defined.  but is there a way to make this more effective? and if I do add anything in the javascript section, will it cause code conflict? or will it be added in?

Comment: the functions defined bellow **are not the same** as the functions passed to onclick handlers

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the wording of the question seems a bit odd. What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: when running jQuery (pardon my wording, i am not the best and proficient english speaker) but i  wanted my functions be defined while running jquery, and avoiding if else

Answer (score 3):

A little confused about what you are trying to do.  The usual way of writing jQuery would be to use anonymous functions, like this:

```
$('document').ready(function{
    var $demo = $('demo');
    $demo.on("click", function() {
        //do something with alpha
    });
    $demo.on("click", function() {
        //do something with beta
    });
});
```

If you want named functions, you would probably do it like this:

```
$('document').ready(function{
    var $demo = $('demo');
    $demo.on("click", runAlpha);
    $demo.on("click", runBeta);
     function runAlpha(){
      //do something with alpha
    }
    function runBeta(){
      //do something with beta
    }
});
```

It sounds like you want to be able to call runAlpha or runBeta outside of the `$(document).ready` portion.  The way I would normally do this would be:

```
$('demo').trigger("click");
```

If you want to call the function directly, move the function definitions outside of the closure:

```
    $('document').ready(function{
    var $demo = $('demo');
    $demo.on("click", function() {
        //do something with alpha
    });
    $demo.on("click", function() {
        //do something with beta
    });
});

function runAlpha(){
    //do something with alpha
}
function runBeta(){
     //do something with beta
}
```

I'd personally do it the first way, as I don't like to "pollute" the global namespace, but it's really your call.

Comment: but will it be"defined" in javascript?

Comment: with your first block of code, can i have another ready function to make all of that go into the function made while running other onclicks?

Comment: you would just trigger the click event on demo in the other onclick